# How to move rules from .htaccess to httpd main server config file?

Tags: .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have approx. 500 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` rules in my `.htaccess` file to block spam referrer websites.

The rules line are as following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hys\.cz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} zzz\.com\.ua [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hypersito\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} tode\.cz [NC,OR]
and many more similar lines
```

Now due to performance issues, I was advised to move these rules to httpd main server config file.

I'm not an expert in this area so can someone please guide me how to do this?

I have access to WHM and shell, both.

I searched on net and found that the file resides in `/etc/httpd/conf` directory. When I opened the `httpd.conf` file, it contained 300+ lines.

Where should I add these `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` rules in `httpd.conf` file and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite does behave a bit differently when used directly in the server config (or virtual host), as opposed to `.htaccess` (or *directory* context).

However, these particular directives should work unaltered in the server config.

It doesn't really matter where in the server config these directives go, providing you don't place them *inside* another directive group. Look for a logical gap in the directives. Blocking directives should go as early as possible after the main server config. (However, as said, the order does not necessarily matter, since Apache modules run independently and in a predefined order anyway.)

However, instead of placing these directives directly in the main config file, I would create a separate config file just for these directives (eg. `block-referer.conf`) and include this file in the main config using an `Include` directive. For example:

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/block-referer.conf
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include

---

**UPDATE:** Since you appear to be using cPanel, it may be preferable to add these directives to an existing include file, since, as the warning in `httpd.conf` states:

> Direct modifications to the Apache configuration file may be lost upon subsequent regeneration of the configuration file.
>   :
>   It is also possible to add custom directives to the various "Include" files loaded by this httpd.conf

Have a look at the following two include files:

> ```
> Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf"
> Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_2.conf"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I create a new `.conf` file, should I direct copy paste the rules lines from `.htaccess` to the new `.conf` file? No extra lines need to be added? No `<directory>` tags, etc? And where should I put the line `Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/block-referer.conf` in `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Yes, assuming you already have `RewriteEngine On` etc. There may already be other `Include` directives later in the file, so you can add it to those. Or, "look for a logical gap in the directives". Without seeing your entire config file we can't say for sure where it would be the most appropriate, but as mentioned, "it [probably] doesn't really matter where in the server config these directives go".

Comment: I have pasted the content of `httpd.conf` file at following link: [link](https://paste.ofcode.org/39dtkuGAwTyF6WFJFVM8tDV). Kindly check and tell me where should I add the include line. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah, you appear to be using cPanel? Are you using name-based virtual hosts? Or just the main server config? I've updated my answer.

Comment: My website is hosted on a managed VPS. Yes, cPanel is installed. I checked both `.conf` files, both are empty. Should I copy paste the referrer block code in any of these 2 files? Which file would you suggest to add the code?

Comment: Yes, try either. `pre_virtualhost_global.conf` would seem logical.

Comment: Thanks. Should I paste the starting lines `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On` or just paste the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]`, etc lines? Also will I need to use `<directory>` tag as well?

Comment: You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper. You probably do need the `RewriteEngine On` directive (as mentioned above). You don't need a `<Directory>` container for these directives.

Comment: I moved one `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hol\.es [NC,OR]` code line from `.htaccess` to the mentioned `.conf` file but when I tried with Chrome referrer blocking plug-in, its not showing 403 forbidden error. Will I need to restart something?

Comment: I restarted Apache Server service, still not blocking the mentioned referrer.

Comment: I tried putting the lines in both files one by one and restarted Apache Server service, still not blocking the mentioned referrer. I even restarted the server using the portal.

Comment: "I moved one `RewriteCond` ..." - I assume you moved the corresponding `RewriteRule` directive as well? (Yes, you will need to restart Apache after making any changes to the server config.)

Comment: Yes. I moved the `RewriteRule` as well. Not working. Will I need to edit any other `.conf` file?

Comment: Ah, when you moved that "one `RewriteCond`" - did you remove the `OR` flag? (Although that would have resulted in every being blocked!)

Comment: Yes. I removed the `OR` flag. It seems to me the rules saved to those files didn't affect anything.

Comment: I fixed the issue and now the rules added to `.conf` files are working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it's now working, how did you "fix" it?

Comment: I searched and found your answer in another thread of this forum. I needed to add `RewriteOptions Inherit` statement in my `.htaccess` file so that it doesn't override rules of `.conf` file. You are really a genius and I appreciate all your help. Thanks.